# Image upload validation in PHP in registration form

Tags: php, image, file-upload, image-upload

I need help with checking if an image has been uploaded and if it has not, set the image path to a default one (Nopic.png).
I am using a form to register users and I need to set a profile image for them.
The form works ok and the image upload works ok (using w3c's code).
But how do I check if the file field is empty or not and set the path accordingly?

Comment: Does any of the answers below work for you? If works accept the answer and if not say it does not work or something and move on.

Answer (score 0):

After upload you can check whether the file exists in the expected directory or not and if not use default image:

```
$image = "../uploads/foo/image.png"; //path to your uploaded image
if(file_exists($image) && (is_file($image))){
    //if exists show the image
}else{
    $image = "../uploads/foo/default.png"; //path to your default image
    //you can then show this image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use is_uploaded_file()

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
echo 'No upload';
}
```

Here is the php documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Thanks guys.
I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

check the file if it exists:

```
    if (file_exists ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']) ) {
        //yes it exist
    }else{
       //default one (Nopic.png)
   }
```